# Backporting a Linux 3.14 driver to 3.4.0

Tags: android, linux, linux-device-driver, android-wireless, backport

I am using Linux version 3.4.0 on my Cyanogenmod-based Nexus 4.
Recently I decided to upgrade my wifi driver to a newer version, which consisted of files I did not have on my current version of Linux, and therefore I decided to use backports in order to accomplish the task.

I started with replacing the file "include/net/cfg80211.h", but more and more problems began to show up as I needed to replace and add more files.

Is there a methodological way of backporting an android-based kernel from a stable version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: You have messed up the text above. Subject as is written should be either "Forward porting..." or "...from 3.14 to 3.4". After that you have clearly describe what is the programming question do you have?

Comment: If you want to update your driver, then perhaps you should first update your kernel from 3.4.0 to 3.4.113 from kernel.org.

Comment: @sawdust, stable kernels do not have the updated drivers. That might only help to update ID list supported by the existing driver (one may achieve this usually without any update at all by using binding interface).

Comment: @0andriy -- As usual you are misconstruing what has been written.  My comment referred to updating the kernel, not retrieving *"updated drivers"*.   For instance, the include file that the OP mentions has been changed.

Comment: @sawdust, as usual you are giving an advice to OP which will not help (and it's explained in my comment why). Moreover, your words _...to update your driver, ... **you should** ... update your kernel from 3.4.0 to 3.4.113_ -- are simply wrong, there is no **should** part involved, there is no *update to the driver*. Try again.

Comment: No, @0andriy, the nuances of the English language elude you. You're misconstruing what I wrote when you chose to omit salient words such as "if",  "perhaps" and "first". In simpler English, my advice is to first update the kernel to the latest patch-level, and then update the driver.  There is no implication that updating the kernel will update the driver (except in your misunderstanding).

Comment: @sawdust, your initial comment I would read as *if you want to achieve something useful, perhaps first you should do something to just waste your time*. Disregard if, perhaps, and first, the whole comment is *do Y* for the question *how to do X*. That's what I'm opposing to.